# RxSwift to Combine: Listening for UIView property update

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

I want to listen for the `isHidden` property of the `UIView` and based on the changes in the value, I am notifying the respective delegates.

I trying to convert the following Rx code to Combine and I am not sure how.

Sample Rx Code:

```
customView.rx
   .observe(Bool.self, "hidden")
   .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      self.view.isHidden = value ?? true
      self.delegate?didUpdate(isHidden: value ?? true)
   })
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Kindly share a few ideas or suggestions.

Note: I am pretty new to **RxSwift** and **Combine** Framework.

Comment: Don't treat your view as if it were a model... The only time the isHidden property changes is if your model changes it, so listen to your model instead of the view.

Answer (score 2):

`NSObject` has a `KeyValueObservingPublisher` that you can subscribe to to get changes to KVO properties. You can create an instance of it yourself or use one of the `publisher(...)` methods to create one.

```swift
view.publisher(for: \.isHidden)
// or
view.publisher(for: \.isHidden, options: [.initial, .new])
```

Comment: Is this the right way? customView.publisher(for:\.isHidden).receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).sink(receiveValue:{ [weak self] value in  })

Comment: You need to store the `AnyCancellable` return by sink.